# How can I extend an object's save function in Parse while still calling the base save function?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I would like to extend the save function of a Parse object, but still call the base implementation of the save function.

```
var parseObj = Parse.Object.extend("ParseObjClassName", {
        save : function(options, arg2, arg3) {
            console.log("new saved method");
            << CALL THE BASE SAVE METHOD >>
        }
    },
    {
        // class methods
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you don't overwrite internal methods like the `save` function as it may cause confusion, however if you must then we can take a look at solutions people have published using Backbone, the library that Parse is based on. For example:

http://enzolutions.com/articles/2015/01/20/how-to-overwrite-backbone-model-save-function/

Adapted for Parse:

```
var parseObj = Parse.Object.extend("ParseObjClassName", {
    save: function(options, arg2, arg3) {
        console.log("new saved method");
        Parse.Object.prototype.save.call(this, options, arg2, arg3);
    }
});
```

In this example we are calling `save` on the `Parse.Object`. However, by invoking it with `call` we can pass in the current execution context as the first argument (`this`) to ensure that the 'save' action is performed on the instance for which the `save` method is called.